# QGis cannot retrieve a text value from QLineEdit

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt, unicode

I am a developing a small plugin with python for QGis. I have a QLineEdit widget
and I need to take the input from there. The input is a 8 character number string.
However when I try to retrieve the text from the QLineEdit python returns a unicode object which does not seem to have any string stored in it.

The QLineEdit field is declared in the constructor my form as follows

`self.combo = QtGui.QLineEdit()`

The text is retireved during a signal-slot call as follows

`the_text = self.combo.text()
print the_text
print len(the_text)`

This should be very simple. Am I doing something wrong or this is a QGis Bug?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example(can be loaded into QGIS as a script) how to create `QLineEdit` widget, connnect it correctly with function and show changing text while editing the entry:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLineEdit


def show_text(text):
    print text


line_edit = QLineEdit()
line_edit.textChanged.connect(show_text)
line_edit.show()
```